# WM_PAINT doesn't redraw figures

Tags: c++, c, winapi

When I hide my window, part of the figure gets erased. I'm using cout to show where my code is running, it seem that every functions are executed but image doesn't get redraw

```
case WM_PAINT:{
        hDC = BeginPaint(ventana,&ps);
        FillRect(hDC,&ps.rcPaint,CreateSolidBrush(RGB(100,100,100)));
        if(hDC){
            CreateFrame(300,200,100,50,&hDC,&ps);
            EndPaint(ventana,&ps);
        }
        break;
    }
```

The function "CreateFrame"

```
int CreateFrame(long x,long y,long ancho,long alto,HDC* dc,PAINTSTRUCT* ps){
RECT rc;
HBRUSH pincel = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
rc.left = ps->rcPaint.left + x;
rc.top = ps->rcPaint.top + y;
rc.right = rc.left + ancho;
rc.bottom = rc.top + alto;

cout<<rc.left<<" - " << rc.top <<" - "<<rc.right<<" - "<<rc.bottom<<"\n";
if(FrameRect(*dc,&rc,pincel)){
    if(Ellipse(*dc,rc.left+10,rc.top+10,rc.left+20,rc.top+20)){
        cout<<"se dibujo elipse\n";
    }
    cout<<"exito\n";
}
DeleteObject(pincel);
return 1;
```

}

[image]

Comment: You probably should show the code that draws the image.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved xdxd

```
int CreateFrame(long x,long y,long ancho,long alto,HDC* dc,PAINTSTRUCT* ps){
RECT rc;
HBRUSH pincel = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
rc.left = x;
rc.top =  y;
rc.right = x + ancho;
rc.bottom = y + alto;

cout<<rc.left<<" - " << rc.top <<" - "<<rc.right<<" - "<<rc.bottom<<"\n";
if(FrameRect(*dc,&rc,pincel)){
    if(Ellipse(*dc,rc.left+10,rc.top+10,rc.left+20,rc.top+20)){
        cout<<"se dibujo elipse\n";
    }
    cout<<"exito\n";
}
DeleteObject(pincel);
return 1;
```

}